# VS 2017 Connected Services Office 365 API not available

Tags: visual-studio-2017, microsoft-graph-api

Cannot find the Office 365 API under conncted services. 
Version: Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 15.9.1 
OS: Windows10

The necessary components are installed:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not VS built-in feature.

> The ASP.NET Providers Connected Service Extension can be installed on
>   Visual Studio 2017. You can install it through Extensions and Updates
>   in Visual Studio and type “ASP.NET Providers Connected Service” in the
>   search box.
>
> To use the Extension, you need to make sure that your web application
>   targets to .NET Framework 4.6.2 or higher.  You can open the extension
>   through right clicking on the project, selecting Add and clicking on
>   Connected Service. You will see all the Connected Services installed
>   on your VS which apply to your project.
>
> https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2018/05/22/announcing-asp-net-providers-connected-service-visual-studio-extension/

[image]